# Running Python FastAPI using IIS encounter "No Python at 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe'"

Tags: python, iis, fastapi, uvicorn

I am trying to get a FastAPI (uvicorn) to work on an IIS server. I am running on Python 3.9.13 and the script works when running through cmd prompt. Here are my steps:

1. Install Python 3.9.13 (added PATH)
2. Installed HTTPPlatformHandler v1.2
3. Created a virtual environment "venv" in C:/test
4. pip installed fastapi[all]
5. Loaded main.py into C:/test

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()
@app.get("/")
def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

6. Checked that script works in cmd prompt and browser

```
uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000
```

7. Started IIS server and added All Web Server (IIS) Application Development except .NET Extensibility 3.5 and ASP .NET 3.5
8. Add website with the following web.config and binding to port 5000

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpPlatform processPath="C:\test\venv\Scripts\python.exe" 
                  arguments="uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%"
                  stdoutLogFile="C:\ML_API_main\LogFiles\python.log">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="SERVER_PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
        <handlers>
            <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

After all that, when I ran the browser, it was a constant loading screen and in the log file generated it will show

```
No Python at 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe'
```

Is there something I missed? I checked that link that the python.exe is available and I can run it from cmd just fine.

The only material that I could find that was close to this was https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win/issues/321, but the solution provided did not help in my case.

I ran the following to grant permission

```
ICACLS c:\test\venv\ /grant "IIS AppPool\test:F"
```

I did not quite understand the second workaround.

**UPDATES 12/5/2022:**
Following comments to not use virtual environment, I had edited and move the folder into wwwroot folder, Now the error changed to HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway:

[image]

Seems like the original issue of not finding the Python.exe has been solved? But will need to troubleshoot another.

**UPDATES 12/5/2022:**

Just in case anyone needs this, I finally managed to get the server working!! I had to grant permission for the Python.exe folder, as well as my code physical directory to IIS_IUSRS. You can do this by just right click > security > change permission. Some folders might not have "IIS_IUSRS" in it, so you will have to add it in manually.

Comment: Try not to use Python virtual environment to host web apps on IIS. Its underlying mechanism (file mappings and so on) is complex and can simply break IIS.

Comment: @LexLi I had moved it out of the virtual environment and shifted it into the wwwroot folder. but now encountered another error "HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway". I have updated the post for the findings.

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ `0x80070005` is not surprising.

Comment: Yes, I came across that article as well. Thanks @LexLi for your help. Managed to get it working.